# Add a Child to the Parent on Button Click Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to add a Label view to the Stacklayout on Button Click in Android.
But It throws Null Pointer exception. Below is what I'm trying to achieve. Can anyone please advice on how to achieve this in xamarin.forms

**Xamarin.Forms Code in C#**

```
 StackLayout parent= new StackLayout ();

 Button add= new Button
        {
            HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.End,
            BackgroundColor=Xamarin.Forms.Color.White,
            Text="ADD",
            TextColor=Xamarin.Forms.Color.Maroon,
        };

 add.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
 
 Label firstLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Label 1",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            TextColor=Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#000000")
        };
 parent.Children.Add(add);
 parent.Children.Add(firstLabel );
```

**Adding Label in ButtonClick**

```
 void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

   Label secondLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Label 1",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            TextColor=Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#000000")
        };
  parent.Children.Add(secondLabel ); 
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I see no reason for this to fail. Could you edit your post with the stack trace you're getting ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code works as is... with one tiny change - make `parent` a class field so it's referenced from within the `OnButtonClicked`

Make sure you update the solution packages so you have the latest Xamarin.Forms. Always update the packages on the solution level so do don't get versioning conflicts

This version was tested and works on iOS:

```
public class LabelPage: ContentPage
    {
        StackLayout parent = null;

        public LabelPage ()
        {
            parent = new StackLayout ();

            Button add = new Button {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White,
                Text = "ADD",
                TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Maroon,
            };

            add.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

            Label firstLabel = new Label {
                Text = "Label 1",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex ("#000000")
            };
            parent.Children.Add (add);
            parent.Children.Add (firstLabel); 

            Content = parent;
        }

        void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            Label secondLabel = new Label {
                Text = "Label 1",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex ("#000000")
            };
            parent.Children.Add (secondLabel); 
            //UpdateChildrenLayout ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In **parent.Children.Add (secondLabel);** _object reference not set to an object_ error

Comment: and when you put a break point over that line which object is null? parent?

Comment: Both are not null.. But it throws a null pointer while running it in Android. I'm not sure about IOS.

Comment: what about parent.Children? is that null? what you're seeing doesn't sound right - did you copy the exact class I posted? Create a new class, copy this exact content, no modifications at all and make App.cs return that as root. The issue is very likely due to some minor detail that will make you slap your forehead once you see it

Comment: Sorry.. I Just cleaned and created a new project it works.. Strange behaviour of xamarin but thanks..