# How to add Clicked Event in Xamarin Forms while using C# 3.0 style

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using `Xamarin.Forms` to add custom render to a button. I need to add a click event on `CmButton` without creating reference variable, or defining outside of the `StackLayout`.

Here is my code:

```
Content = new StackLayout 
{
    Children 
    {
        new CmButton 
        {
            Text = "SIGN UP| AGREE TO TERMS",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            BorderColor = Color.Transparent,
            BorderWidth = 0,
            TextColor = Color.White
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want click event within the new Button{} block

Use `Command` instead of `Click`

```
   var btn = new Button
   {
       Text = "",
       Command = new Command(()=> 
       {
       })
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use-

```
 Button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
```

It will create a click event of button as-

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

For more detail:- https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/VS-Toolbox-Xamarin-Forms
 and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/

Comment: I want click event within the new Button{} block

Comment: see the above links. If it does not help you.. you can check button click event here on SO- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929977/add-a-child-to-the-parent-on-button-click-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your button to a variable to use events.

```
myButton = new CmButton 
           {
               Text = "SIGN UP| AGREE TO TERMS",
               BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
               BorderColor = Color.Transparent,
               BorderWidth = 0,
               TextColor = Color.White
           }

Content = new StackLayout 
{
    Children 
    {
        myButton
    }
}

myButton.Clicked += (o, e) => { 
                                 //click event handler 
                              };
```